Doubt on conservation of angular momentum for Kepler's laws
Just before proving Kepler's laws, my Professor claimed that if $\vec{F}$ is a central force with center $O$ and it is the only force acting on a point $P$, then the trajectory of $P$ is a curve plane. The proof of this lemma started from the fact that the angular momentum $\vec{L^O}$ is a constant of motion for central forces, so $\vec{r}\times m\vec{v} = \vec{r_0} \times m\vec{v_0} $. Then he stated that

therefore the motion must take place on a plane since $\vec{L^O} = \vec{L_0^O}$

and also that if $\vec{r_0} \parallel \vec{v_0}$ then the motion actually takes place on a straight line. Why are these statements true? Thanks in advance.
EDIT:
I got the explanation of the first statement, but the second claim is still not clear to me. I would like to see that $\vec{r} \parallel \vec{r_0}$, so that clearly the motion takes place on the straight line parallel to $ \vec{r_0}$. In principle, $\vec{r_0} \parallel \vec{v_0}$ and $\vec{r} \parallel \vec{v}$, so that $\vec{L^O_0} = \vec{L^O} = 0$, say nothing about the relation between $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{r_0}$.

A central force, by definition, only varies with distance. So the force is not affecting any angular momentum and the angular momentum is therefore conserved.

@DavideMasi FYI, This is the correct explanation. The complete derivation which I wrote out the whole derivation on your math stackexchange post follows exactly this logic! Hopefully, you can use that to fill in the details for why that comment was correct.

The definition of a plane can be written as $\vec{a}\cdot \vec{r} = 0$, where $\vec{a}$ is any vector perpendicular to the plane.
In this case, you have a vector quantity $\vec{L}$, which is from its definition, a vector perpendicular to a plane, since $(\vec{r}\times \vec{v})\cdot \vec{r} = 0$.
Then, since angular momentum is conserved, the vector $\vec{L}$ does not change, even though the position does, and so the body must still be in the plane defined by $\vec{L}\cdot \vec{r}=0$.
If $\vec{r}_0$ and $\vec{v}_0$ are parallel, then the angular momentum is zero. If it cannot change then $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ must always be parallel. The only way this can be arranged is straight line motion towards or away from the origin since any deviation from that will result in a non-zero $\vec{L}$.
I see your edit. But $\vec{v} = d\vec{r}/dt$ so any change in $\vec{r}$ can only be in the same direction as $\vec{v}$ (and hence $\vec{r}$) - i.e. along a radial line. In other words
$$ \vec{r}(t) = \vec{r}_0 + \int \vec{v}\ dt = \vec{r_0} + \alpha(t)\vec{r_0} $$
where $\alpha$ is a scalar that depends on the central force considered, the mass of the object and the initial velocity.  $\vec{v}$ can never have a non-radial component if its initial value is radial, since a central force imparts no non-radial acceleration.

You explained the first part very well, thank you. Could you please clarify the second one too? I don't get it intuitively nor does it look formal enough to me. If you wish, edit your answer and I will accept it

Please check my edit

Thanks for your patience, but as an aspiring mathematician I must admit that I am not convinced yet - I'd like a proof with symbols and not words since I find it hard to follow your logic reasoning. What I mean is that it seems quite obvious that the motion must take place on a straight line, but I'm still not sure about this fact

Could you please explain the tricky part $\int \vec{v}\ dt = \alpha(t)\vec{r_0}$?

$\vec{v} = d\vec{r}/dt$ but since $\vec{v}$ is always parallel $\vec{r}$ then we can say $\vec{v} = \beta \vec{r_0}$ where $\beta$ is a time-dependent scalar and its integral is $\alpha(t)$. $\vec{v}$ can never have a non-radial component if its initial value is radial, since a central force imparts no non-radial acceleration. @DavideMasi

I swear I don't get it. Shouldn't it be $\vec{v} = \beta \vec{r}$ without $_0$, given the fact that $\vec{v} \parallel \vec{r}$?

If you like. Then $\vec{r} = \vec{r_0}/(1 - \alpha(t)) = \alpha'(t)\vec{r_0}$. @DavideMasi

I don't understand where these equations come from!

I got a rigorous proof from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4945194/how-to-prove-two-vectors-are-parallel-given-the-conservation-of-the-angular-mome/4945260?noredirect=1#comment10573646_4945260 so I decided to accept your answer for the clear explanation of the first part. Thank you very much for your patience and kindness, I appreciate it a lot

The angular momentum ${\bf L}$ of a point-like particle is proportional to the vector product of position ${\bf r}$ and velocity ${\bf v}$. It is a vector orthogonal to the plane containing ${\bf r}$ and ${\bf v}$.
Therefore, the constancy of ${\bf L}$ implies that ${\bf r}$ and ${\bf v}$ are always in the same plane (if it wouldn't be so, the direction of ${\bf L}$ should change).
The special case ${\bf L}=0$ corresponds to the case of the same direction for ${\bf r}$ and ${\bf v}$. I.e., the motion is rectilinear.

I'm still not sure why the trajectory should be on the plane of $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$. I know it seems very intuitive, but I don't see how it should be proved formally.

Probably my problem is that I don't have a clear idea of what the definition or plane/rectilinear motion is and how this is related to the direction of $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$. In one exercise we solved in class, which required to prove that a trajectory was an ellipse, we were able to find the equation of the trajectory and observe it was the equation of an ellipse, but here I don't have any equations so I don't get how it is possible to say that the trajectory is plane or rectilinear. Hope I was clear enough

Note that if $L\neq 0$, the plane of motion is simply the plane perpendicular to $\vec{L}$.

@DavideMasi, as the answer stated, if the motion is not fixed to a plane, that implies that angular momentum is changing (cross product produce a vector that is perpendicular to the plane two vectors form), which violates the conservation of angular momentum, meaning the motion must take place in a fix plane that is not changing, so angular momentum does not change direction.

@DavideMasi Equations are not a substitute for concepts. However, if you feel more comfortable with equations, a "constructive" formal proof goes as follows: in the case of ${\bf L} \neq 0$, the orthogonality of angular momentum and position (easily proved algebraically) implies the constraint on the trajectory ${\bf L}\cdot {\bf r}= constant$, which is the equation of a plane.

@Polaris5744 I know that the cross product of $\vec{r}$ and $\vec{v}$ is perpendicular to both, but this fact alone didn't help me to understand why the motion must take place in a plane. The last answer I received clarifies this point but I still have a doubt on the last part

@GiorgioP-DoomsdayClockIsAt-90 now I see. Probably, as the other answer suggested, in this case it is $\vec{L} \cdot \vec{r}=0$, right?
